# What is Meriva Phytosome Curcumin?

Tags: botany, food

What is Meriva Phytosome Curcumin other than being a food supplement?

Is it a plant? A type of plant extract?

I googled it but still couldn't figure out exactly what it is.

The reason I'm asking is because I came across the following list in a site selling vitamins and other food supplements:

```
Meriva Phytosome Curcumin
Turmeric (Curcumin)
Turmeric Formulas
```

It wasn't clear to me if `Meriva Phytosome Curcumin` is a specific kind of curcumin since it seems to be sold under a few different brands.

Answer (score 2):

Well, http://meriva.org states that

> Meriva® is a patented formulation of curcumin, a dietary phenolic, with soy lecithin (non-GMO)(1). The two compounds form a non-covalent adduct in a 1:2 weight ratio, and two parts of microcrystalline cellulose are then added to improve formulation, with an overall contents of curcumin of 20%

A [phytosome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phytosome) is

> [...]  a complex of a natural active ingredient and a phospholipid.
>
> It is claimed that phytosome increases absorption of "conventional herbal extracts" or isolated active principles both topically as well as orally.
>
> The complexation with phospholipid has been applied to many popular herbal extract or active molecules including [...] curcumin isolated from turmeric [...].

And [Curcumin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curcumin) is

> [...] is a diarylheptanoid. It is the principal curcuminoid of turmeric, which is a member of the ginger family (Zingiberaceae). Turmeric's other two curcuminoids are desmethoxycurcumin and bis-desmethoxycurcumin. The curcuminoids are natural phenols that are responsible for the yellow color of turmeric. Curcumin can exist in several tautomeric forms, including a 1,3-diketo form and two equivalent enol forms. The enol form is more energetically stable in the solid phase and in solution.

So, Meriva Phytosome Curcumin is a phytosome of curcumin developed by Meriva.

Comment: When I googled it I didn't reach any of those (except curcumin), perhaps because Google results are personalized...

Comment: @traveh It's not that it's personalised, it's that you have to know how to look for the answer. Adding things like "NCBI" or "PLOS ONE" to the end will help you find scholarly articles (same with using google scholar). Also, it might help to break things down into different parts, like searching for Miriva, phytosome and curcumin sepeartely. If you add quotations around a part of the search, that part is prioritised by google.

Answer (score 0):

To summarize terdon's excellent answer:

curcumin is a chemical found in the plant turmeric (*Curcuma longa*)

Comment: I know what curcumin is, I was wonder what is "Meriva Phytosome Curcumin" specifically. :)